# Only show a property in inspector when multiple other properties are set

Tags: neoscms

I want to only show a property in the inspector when multiple other properties are set, like:

```
'Example.Example:Content.Whatever':
  properties:
    prop1:
      type: boolean
    prop2:
      type: boolean
    prop3:
      type: string
      ui:
        inspector:
          hidden: 'ClientEval:node.properties.prop1 ? false : {ClientEval:node.properties.prop2 ? true : false}'
```

This example doesn't work, but maybe it explains my intention.

The official neos [docs](https://docs.neos.io/cms/manual/content-repository/nodetype-properties#depending-properties) only have an example for **1** condition which works but is not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made it almost. You have just to use `&&` to combine it in your if statement

This will hide the element if the other two properties are `true`:

```
    test:
      type: boolean
      ui:
        label: 'test dependent hidden'
        inspector:
          group: general
    test2:
      type: boolean
      ui:
        label: 'test2 dependent hidden'
        inspector:
          group: general
    hideMe:
      type: boolean
      ui:
        label: 'hideme dependent hidden'
        inspector:
          group: general
          hidden: 'ClientEval:node.properties.test && node.properties.test2 ? true : false'
```